# AWS API Gateway Issue with android generated code

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, crash, aws-api-gateway

I am new to the AWS API Gateway, we have cloud APIs working fine, but I am facing an issue with the android generated code for those APIs.
I followed the steps to setup the sdk from the link below
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html

The application is crashing as soon as I make one of the POST method calls from the generated code.

```
ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory().endpoint("endpoint url");
final IDClient client = factory.build(IDClient.class);
client.authenticateUser(token); --> the app crashes here, token is a string parameter.
```

The logs show: `"AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1"`

We are not using IAM so Im not setting the credentials in the APIClientFactory
I have tested the cloud API and it works fine with the given input parameters. so I am pretty sure its the way I am invoking the method thats causing the issue but Im unable to root cause it.

Added the stack trace when app crashes

```
12-15 17:08:04.532 25761-27042/awsgw.com.awsgw I/AWSGS: doInBackground
12-15 17:08:04.552 25761-27042/awsgw.com.awsgw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
12-15 17:08:04.552 25761-27042/awsgw.com.awsgw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
12-15 17:08:04.552 25761-27042/awsgw.com.awsgw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
12-15 17:08:04.552 25761-27042/awsgw.com.awsgw D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
12-15 17:08:04.562 25761-27042/awsgw.com.awsgw E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: awsgw.com.awsgw, PID: 25761
12-15 17:08:04.572 25761-27042/awsgw.com.awsgw I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25761 SIG: 9
```

Comment: here is the stacktrace when the app crashes

Comment: the stacktrace doesn't show any error related to the generated client.